# R bookdown - math in table-header not working

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

After cloning the [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) i tried to get a table with some math in the header. In the html-output everything works fine. In the PDF output it is broken:

Chunk:

````
```{r}
knitr::kable(
  head(cars),
  col.names = c("$y_{speed}$", "$y_{dist}$")
)
```
````

Bookdown - PDF: (Here you can see the wrong output)

[image]

Rmarkdown - PDF: (Result as expected)

[image]

Bookdown - HTML: (Result as expected)

[image]

This is the Latex-Code bookdown produces:

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{knitr::}\KeywordTok{kable}\NormalTok{(}
  \KeywordTok{head}\NormalTok{(cars),}
  \DataTypeTok{col.names =} \KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"$y_\{speed\}$"}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"$y_\{dist\}$"}\NormalTok{)}
\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{tabular}{r|r}
\hline
\$y\_\{speed\}\$ & \$y\_\{dist\}\$\\
\hline
4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 10\\
\hline
7 & 4\\
\hline
7 & 22\\
\hline
8 & 16\\
\hline
9 & 10\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the argument `escape = F` for `kable` since there seems to be a double escaping of special characters in bookdown.